# (JAVA) How to add selenium webdriver window inside AWT.Frame to use Action Listeners

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, recorder

I Want to make something similar to the **Selenium IDE**, to be a part of automation solution.uch that when I open the web driver browser, it begins to listen to my mouse and keyboard actions then actions get listed in the console window

What I've tried to do is to create a new Class called "DriverListener" and this class inherits the *"Frame"* class to be able to use the *"MouseListener"*, then it implements *"WebDriver"*, *"MouseListener"* interfaces

I implemented all the needed methods for both "webDriver" to be able to use it's functionality and "Mouse Listener" to be able to listen to the actions done on the webDriver

but currently, I need to know how to add the webDriver browser inside the Frame that is responsible to actions listening

**Sample of Code:**

```
public class DriverListener extends Frame implements WebDriver, MouseListener
{
    private WebDriver lDriver;
    private Frame driverFrame;

    public DriverListener(WebDriver driver)
    {
        lDriver = driver;
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

// WebDriver methods implementation
    public void get(String url) 
    {
        lDriver.get(url);
    }
.
.
.
    public Options manage() 
    {
        return lDriver.manage();
    }

// mouseListener methods implementation
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Mouse Clicked ");
        System.out.println("X: "+ e.getX()+ " Y: "+ e.getY());      
    }
.
.
.
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Mouse Release ");
        System.out.println("X: "+ e.getX()+ " Y: "+ e.getY());      
    }

//Frame Initialization
    private void initializeFrame()
    {
        driverFrame = new Frame();
        int xPosition = lDriver.manage().window().getPosition().getX();
        int yPosition = lDriver.manage().window().getPosition().getY();
        int width = lDriver.manage().window().getSize().getWidth();
        int height = lDriver.manage().window().getSize().getHeight();

        Rectangle frameWindow = new Rectangle(xPosition, yPosition, width, height);
        driverFrame.setBounds(frameWindow);
        driverFrame.setLayout(null);
        driverFrame.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same problem as mine or needs help in the same topic, I found a programmatic tool that is very useful called **BRAP** (Browser Recorder And Player) based on Java, you can check the tool through this link. https://github.com/nobal/BRAP